# Unable to access my own web page OSX Server

Tags: mac, dns, website, osx-mavericks

I have recently set up a Mac mini server in my home. I have configured the DNS settings manually by creating a primary zone being my domain and then a machine record (A Record) in order to configure the right host name. I've checked this the usual way in terminal and it returns success.

Before I go ahead and configure my mail, I noticed that I was unable to view my website. From within my network on any device.

NB. My website is hosted externally with a third party.

I have Mac Mini running Mavericks 10.9.1 and Server 3.0.2, I'm using a 2TB Time Capsule as the router which plugs directly into my fibre modem. Ports are opened correctly as I have done this through the Server App panel where I can see my Time Capsule.

I've obtained the IP of the website and when I tried pinging it from terminal it cannot resolve. I've contacted Apple, and after 2 hours on the phone to them, I've been told it's out of the scope of their support.

If this is DNS, can someone help, because I'm pulling my hair out!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by removing all the zones in the DNS panel. Create a new zone with domain, the set up an A record with your host name. After which create a new A record as your domain.

The site can then be viewed again.